# How to get month name by month number inside the query using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the count of added records by month. Following query is working fine

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) AS count_by_month, MONTH(date_added) AS in_month
FROM      `promotion` 
WHERE     YEAR(date_added) = '2016' 
GROUP BY  MONTH(date_added)
```

But above query is returning month number in the result, I wanted to get the month name like `Jan`,`Feb` instead of number. I tried following trick but it does not working.

```
    SELECT    COUNT(*) AS count_by_month, 
    MONTH(date_added) AS in_month, MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(in_month, '%m'));
    FROM      `ws_promotion` 
    WHERE     YEAR(date_added) = '2016' 
    GROUP BY  MONTH(date_added)
```

Can anyone guide me how can fix the issue, i would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT    
    COUNT(*) AS count_by_month, 
    MONTH(date_added) AS in_month, 
    MONTHNAME(date_added)
FROM      `ws_promotion` 
WHERE     YEAR(date_added) = '2016' 
GROUP BY  MONTH(date_added)
```

**Note:** `MONTHNAME(date)` function expects `date` as argument.

**Example:**

```
mysql> SELECT MONTHNAME('2009-05-18');
+-------------------------+
| MONTHNAME('2009-05-18') |
+-------------------------+
| May                     | 
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

**More:**
If you want to get month name from numbers then you can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the number to a date, and then back with `MONTHNAME()`

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(7, '%m'));

+---------------------------------+
| MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(7, '%m')) |
+---------------------------------+
| July                            |
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: You are welcome :). I've updated the answer with more details.